# Getting all the lines inbetween two strings and storing the data in another file in python 2.7

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a method to find all the lines in between two strings for example

```
'X_0_Gui_Menu_322_Menu_Outputs_SDI_overlays'
'X_0_Gui_Menu_321_Menu_Outputs_SDI_processing'
12:Button 11 released.
Wheel 4 turned from 31 to 30.
Button 9 pressed.
'X_0_Gui_Menu_321_Menu_Outputs_SDI_processing'
'X_0_Gui_Menu_322_Menu_Outputs_SDI_overlays'
Button 9 released.
  Setting parameters saved.
     Wheel 4 turned from 29 to 34.
     Button 9 pressed.
     'X_0_Gui_Menu_322_Menu_Outputs_SDI_overlays'
     'X_0_Gui_Menu_3231_Menu_Outputs_SDI_status'
```

So the output from the files should be

**File 1**

Button 11 released.
 Wheel 4 turned from 31 to 30.
 Button 9 pressed.

**File 2**

Button 9 released.
 Setting parameters saved.
 Wheel 4 turned from 29 to 34.
 Button 9 pressed.

and so on..

I tried to implement in the following code but isn't working as expected

```
with open("messages", "r") as fin:
    lines = (line.strip('PAGE(enter)\n') for line in fin)
    blocks = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(lines, bool) if k]
    file = 0
    for block in blocks:
        file = file + 1
        with open("commands_executed" + str(file), "a") as data_inside_page:
            data_inside_page.write(str(blocks))
```

Comment: did you mean `PAGE(leave)`  by `PAGE(exit)` ?

Comment: @kasra Exactly sorry edited it again !

Comment: `str.strip` does not remove whole strings, it just removes characters out of a list (so every P, A, G, E, (, e, … at the beginning and the end would be removed from the string).  How about simply iterate over the list of lines?

Comment: Your input file ends with an 'enter' line.  How shall this special (error) case be handled?  In my solution you will get a file for this unfinished block (in this case it's an empty file because no line follows the start marker).  Is this what you'd expect?

Comment: @Alfe That's not a problem. Any way I need to parse the file to check the data again. So empty file doesn't hurt !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'PAGE\(enter\)[\S ]+\s((?:(?![^\n]+PAGE\(leave\)).)*)', re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
test_str = u"Jan 01 01:25:08 AMIRA-134500021 user.notice gui-monitor[770]: ACTION:401b0836:8:PAGE(leave) 'X_0_Gui_Menu_322_Menu_Outputs_SDI_overlays'\nJan 01 01:25:08 AMIRA-134500021 user.notice gui-monitor[770]: ACTION:401b0836:8:PAGE(enter) 'X_0_Gui_Menu_321_Menu_Outputs_SDI_processing'\nJan 01 01:25:09 AMIRA-134500021 user.notice butler[774]: LOG:200708a0:12:Button 11 released.\nJan 01 01:25:12 AMIRA-134500021 user.notice butler[774]: LOG:200708a0:12:Wheel 4 turned from 31 to 30.\nJan 01 01:25:12 AMIRA-134500021 user.notice butler[774]: LOG:200708a0:12:Button 9 pressed.\nJan 01 01:25:12 AMIRA-134500021 user.notice gui-monitor[770]: ACTION:401b0836:8:PAGE(leave) 'X_0_Gui_Menu_321_Menu_Outputs_SDI_processing'\nJan 01 01:25:12 AMIRA-134500021 user.notice gui-monitor[770]: ACTION:401b0836:8:PAGE(enter) 'X_0_Gui_Menu_322_Menu_Outputs_SDI_overlays'\nJan 01 01:25:25 AMIRA-134500021 user.notice butler[774]: LOG:200708a0:12:Button 9 released.\nJan 01 01:25:25 AMIRA-134500021 user.notice concen[655]: LOG:2011088a:4:Setting parameters saved.\nJan 1 01:25:27 AMIRA-134500021 daemon.warn dnsmasq-dhcp[738]: DHCP packet received on eth0 which has no address\nJan 01 01:25:28 AMIRA-134500021 user.notice butler[774]: LOG:200708a0:12:Wheel 4 turned from 29 to 34.\nJan 01 01:25:28 AMIRA-134500021 user.notice butler[774]: LOG:200708a0:12:Button 9 pressed.\nJan 01 01:25:28 AMIRA-134500021 user.notice gui-monitor[770]: ACTION:401b0836:8:PAGE(leave) 'X_0_Gui_Menu_322_Menu_Outputs_SDI_overlays'\nJan 01 01:25:28 AMIRA-134500021 user.notice gui-monitor[770]: ACTION:401b0836:8:PAGE(enter) 'X_0_Gui_Menu_3231_Menu_Outputs_SDI_status'"

ll=re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Try this.Write each of element of list `ll` to a file.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/37

Comment: I tried this first. It works perfectly for me ! Thank you so much :)

Comment: This will only work completely in-memory :-/  But if this is no problem for you, so be it.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need regular expressions for this , just read all the lines with `readlines()` then slice the lines array from where `'PAGE(start)'` is in that line to where `'PAGE(leave)'` is in  :

```
new=[]
start=0
with open('your_file.txt','r') as f :
    a= f.readlines()
    for i,j in enumerate(a):
        if 'PAGE(enter)' in j :
            start=i
            continue
        if 'PAGE(leave)' in j :
            if len (a[start+1:i]):
               new.append(a[start+1:i])

with open('new_file1','w') as f1 ,open('new_file2','w') as f2:
 for line in new[0] :
    f1.write(line)
 for line in new[1] :
    f2.write(line)
```

new_file1 :

```
Button 11 released.
Wheel 4 turned from 31 to 30.
Button 9 pressed.
```

new_file2:

```
Button 9 released.
Setting parameters saved.
Wheel 4 turned from 29 to 34.
Button 9 pressed.
```

Comment: Reading the whole file into memory in the beginning isn't necessary for this task (and maybe a problem for large input).

Comment: @Alfe yes , surely i just write for this problem but i think always must use the complete and optimized solution ! , thanks for your reminding !

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Python 2.7):

```
import re

START_REGEX = re.compile(r"PAGE\(enter\)")
END_REGEX = re.compile(r"PAGE\(leave\)")
file = 0
with open("messages", "r") as fin:
  for line in fin:
    if not START_REGEX.search(line): continue
    commands = []
    for included_line in fin:
      if END_REGEX.search(included_line):
        file += 1
        with open("commands_executed" + str(file), "a") as data_inside_page:
          for command in commands: data_inside_page.write(command)
        break
      else:
        commands.append(included_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sth Pythonic using generators like this:

```
def eachBlock(inFile):

    lineIterator = iter(inFile)

    def eachBlockLine():
        while True:  # until an end-line is found
            line = lineIterator.next()
            if matchesEnd(line):
                break
            yield line

    while True:  # until the end of file
        line = lineIterator.next()
        if matchesStart(line):
            yield eachBlockLine()

with open('input-file') as inFile:
    for i, block in enumerate(eachBlock(inFile)):
        with open('output-file-%d' % i, 'w') as outFile:
            for line in block:
                outFile.write(line)
```

A solution like this is completely streaming the whole input, nothing (large) gets stored in memory.  But maybe your input (the file, the blocks therein) never is so large that this is important.